# SQL Sorting Strings and Numbers

Tags: sql

If I have a list of `1,2,3,4,5,K` and I want it ordered like `K,1,2,3,4,5` how can I do this in SQL?  Those values are the only ones in the SQL table.  This is in MySQL, but other databases are also welcomed.

Comment: It's not clear whether these are rows in a table/resultset, or a single string of comma-separated values in which you want the order of the values changed.

Comment: What are your rules for sorting? Letters before numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no integer dection function in mysql, so you'll have to do something like this.  Assuming your column is varchar or the like, you could something simple like this

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN field REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$' THEN field ELSE '0'+field END
```

Comment: Cant I convert it to a signed int?

Comment: Sure, but when it fails, you'll have a null.  This does it in one step

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you could do:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN column='K' THEN 0 ELSE TO_NUMBER(column) END
```

Other systems presumably have similar constructs.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to sort the SELECT's result, then you might just declare your custom sorting rules in ORDER BY statement.

Here's an example: http://www.emadibrahim.com/2007/05/25/custom-sort-order-in-a-sql-statement/

The idea is to assign your own priority to each item.

Bear in mind that it might be dependant on the actual SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that works in SQLite:

```
 select v1.* from (
   select t3.*, (case when value = 'K' then '0' else value end) normalized_val 
   from t3) v1 
 order by v1.normalized_val;
```